# How to point a next js app to run off port 80 in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, ubuntu, next.js, virtual-machine

I have successfully created a build of NextJS app in Azure DevOps Linux server, I now want to run it off of port 80 for NGINX. How can I do that. Can someone please provide a step by step process for this?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Comment: As far as I know, you can't run NextJS app in NGINX. You need to run node.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want your nextJS app to be accessible on port 80 on your VM.
Assuming you already have setup the VM correctly and running your nextJS app on localhost. You can run Next.js app on port 80 with Nginx reverse proxy:

1. Provision Ubuntu VM on Azure [you've done this]
2. SSH into Azure Ubuntu VM [you've done this]
3. Run a Next.js app e.g on port 3000 [you've done this]
4. Update packages and install nginx on the VM
5. Configure Nginx reverse proxy using file:
   `/etc/nginx/conf.d/nextjs.conf`
6. In the nginx config, reverse proxy port 80 to the port Next.js is listening on on your VM(3000)

```
server {
  listen 80; 
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

7. Handle port 80 access.

```bash
# Allow binding port 80 
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /usr/sbin/nginx
```

9. Start Nginx with main config file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. This will load the main nginx.conf which includes any config files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

```bash
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Hope this helps.